# Python GUI toggle button trying to toggle a label image

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label, toggle

Can i ask for a little help please? I've created a GUI with a toggle button which toggles the button text LED ON, LED OFF.  I've now added a label with an image and I would like to try to make the label image toggle when the button is pressed.

I've looked up some examples but I can't quite see how, or where, to add the code to make the label image toggle as well.
I tried to add a piece of code into the first part of my IF statement, using label.config but I was trying things I had read on the forums but in the end it didn't work. So I've come to ask for advice.

Thanks for any help.

My code....

```
# Idle 07_02_LED ON using GUI
from time import sleep

from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master): 
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)



            Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)

            self.button = Button(frame, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
            self.button.grid(row=2, column=0)

            LED = Label(frame, image=logo).grid(row=2, column=1)

    def convert0(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 0 OFF')
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 OFF')
            LED = Label.config(image = logo2)
        else:
            print('LED 0 ON')
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 ON')


root = Tk()
logo = PhotoImage(file="C:\My Documents\MyPictures\Green LED.gif")
logo2 = PhotoImage(file="C:\My Documents\My Pictures\Red LED.gif")

root.wm_title('LED on & off program')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `LED` with `self.LED`.

```
class App:

    def __init__(self, master): 
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)

            self.button = Button(frame, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
            self.button.grid(row=2, column=0)

            self.LED = Label(frame, image=logo)
            self.LED.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def convert0(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 0 OFF')
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 OFF')
            self.LED.config(image = logo2)
        else:
            print('LED 0 ON')
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 ON')
            self.LED.config(image = logo)
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me but thanks anyway. I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: @blast_uk Sorry I made a mistake at the end of `__init__`. `Label.grid` doesn't return itself. Now corrected.

Comment: I did manage to work it out with your comments and some searching and understanding of other posts.  Thanks again.